# Is it possible to treat a table as read only in hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I have some tables for which I have no reason to ever update from within the application, so I would like to prevent it from happening even accidentally by a bug somewhere else.

I see the `@Immutable` annotation, but it looks like that will still allow insertions and deletions.  I'd like to full on treat the whole table (not just each entity) as written in stone.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Or do I misunderstand the documentation on `@Immutable`?

If an example is needed, lets say that there is a table with `MONTH` table, and a `Month` entity, and a `APPOINTMENT` table with a `Appointment` entity associated.  I would never want to delete or insert a row into month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried read only caching strategy:

> If your application needs to read, **but not modify**, instances of a persistent class, a read-only cache can be used. This is the simplest and optimal performing strategy. It is even safe for use in a cluster.

From: [19.2.2. Strategy: read only](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache-readonly)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think this is what I need.  From the documentation, it looks like this will at least take care of optimizing from a performance standpoint.  I have not had time to verify for myself if this does the main thing I want, which is to _prevent_ the application from attempting a save/update/delete.  When I get a chance to verify that, I'll accept an answer or post comment.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `READ_ONLY` transactions by putting `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` over the method.

`http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/04/read-only-transactions-with-spring-and.html`.

Another method : As far as isolation levels go, if your table is never inserted or updated you can use the READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation level, which allows dirty reads, non-repeatable reads and phantom reads. However none of that matters since the data is never changing.

You can look at the different isolation levels and effects of each in the spring javadocs (`http://docs.huihoo.com/javadoc/spring/2.5/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html`)

This will free up locks on rows the most and will give you the best performance, at least as far as locking goes

Comment: The isolation level thing appears to help will help with performance, thanks for letting me know about it.  But will it actually prevent reads/saves/updates?  The Transactional(readOnly=true) is also good to know, I think in some cases this could be perfect. If you could set it for a whole entity, it would be perfect.

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think so. It will allow inserts but it is fast as no lock is issued. To handle INSERTS use readOnly=true option. It will throw an exception while inserting.
I will confirm if correct answer is otherwise.